# Whats the most pythonic way to do this?

Tags: python, coding-style, styles

This is just a curiosity question really. My code works. I have a large array of instances that I'm attempting to break into different groups (training, validation, and testing). They're represented in a single list, but it is important that they stay in groups of 23. Here's my implementation:

```
train_end = int(len(instances)*TRAINING_END)
while train_end % CHANNELS != 0:
    train_end -= 1
valid_end = int(len(instances)*VALIDATION_END)
while valid_end % CHANNELS != 0:
    valid_end += 1
```

And then I partition the lists using `[:train_end], [train_end:valid_end], [valid_end:]`. I feel like everything that takes this many steps in python has a simpler way. Any ideas?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is probably a more appropriate place for this

Comment: Take a look at this video about looping constructs in python http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the while loops by doing:

```
train_end = (int(len(instances)*TRAINING_END) // CHANNELS) * CHANNELS
```

The effect of this is to make sure that `int(len(instances)*TRAINING_END)` is divisible by `CHANNELS`.

For `valid_end`, equivalent effect is:

```
valid_end = (int(len(instances)*VALIDATION_END) // CHANNELS + 1) * CHANNELS
```